# Website URL does not change when subsequent pages are loaded

Tags: url, subdomain

I can make a subdomain and connect it with the domain name, but here is a problem that when
any page is open in my website my website URL does not change. It remain same as my domain name, but if I open my site with my subdomain name it works well.

Here is my site check it:

[www.testmydomainname.tk](http://www.testmydomainname.tk)

Answer (score 0):

Your hosting provider loads your website into a [frameset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp), when you navigate through your site's pages, only the current frame URL changes, but not the parent (top) frame.

For example, when you view the source of your www.testmydomainname.tk site:

```
<frameset rows="*">
    <frame frameborder=0 src="http://azelead.westlinkpk.com" name="dot_tk_frame_content" scrolling="auto" noresize>
</frameset>
```

Your hosting provider probably uses this method to serve advertisements to cover the costs of a "free" domain name.

You can fix this by placing this tag in the `<head>` of all the pages of your website to break out of frames for all links, and to use the original URL your site is hosted on:

```
<base target="_top" />
```